# Whats the probability of three parts failing given

Tags: probability

Given that a machine has three parts. Probability that A fails is $10^{-5}$. Probability of B failing given A fails is $10^{-1}$ and $10^{-5}$ otherwise. Probability of C failing given B fails is $10^{-1}$ and $10^{-5}$ otherwise.

1. Whats the probability that all parts fail together?
2. Whats the probability that two or more parts fail?

For 1

$\boldsymbol{P~}(A \bigcap B \bigcap C) = \boldsymbol{P~}(A) \boldsymbol{P~}(B | A)\boldsymbol{P~}(C~ |~A \bigcap B)$

How to calculate $\boldsymbol{P~}(C~ |~A \bigcap B)?$

For 2

$\boldsymbol{P}($Two or more parts fail$) = 1 -\boldsymbol{P}(~$ {None parts fail}  $~\bigcup~$  { Exactly 1 part fails} )

$\boldsymbol{P}($Two or more parts fail$) = 1 -\boldsymbol{P}(~ \{(\bar{A}~\bigcap~\bar{B}~\bigcap~\bar{C} )\}  ~\bigcup~$  { Exactly 1 part fails} )

Again, similar expression $\boldsymbol{P}(~ \{(\bar{A}~\bigcap~\bar{B}~\bigcap~\bar{C} )\}$. How do I proceed?

If I plot the binary tree diagram then I see that the 
$\boldsymbol{P~}(A \bigcap B \bigcap C)~ = ~10^{-5}\times10^{-1}\times10^{-1} ~=~ 10^{-7}$ Is it correct?

Kindly help.

Comment: As you have found, you need some more information about the interaction of the three.

Comment: @Henry What minimum information would help to solve the question?

Comment: $\boldsymbol{P}(C \mid A \cap B)$ plus what you already have would answer (1).  To get (2) I suspect you might also want a second piece of information, such as $\boldsymbol{P}(C \mid A)$

Comment: @Henry I have reworded the problem. Can you comment on the possible solution. Thanks.